# PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments method in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments method.  how can I integrate this method ? please provide a sample code with an example in PHP language
This is my curl api request please check it and tell me where is my mistake

Request Code :-

```
$header_info = array(
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID:'=>'test@gmail.com', 
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD:'=>'************', 
    'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE:'=>'***************',
    'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT:'=>'NV', 
    'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT:'=>'NV', 
    'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID:'=>'QVH6C2AC7VWW2',
       );

$nvpStr_='actionType=PAY_PRIMARY&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1¤cyCode=SGD&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&memo=Example&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=25.00&receiverList.receiver(0).email=retailah@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=5.00&receiverList.receiver(1).email=merchant@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US&returnUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/success.html&cancelUrl=http://www.yourdomain.com/cancel.html';      

$API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";
// $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";

 $version = urlencode('51.0');
 // Set the curl parameters.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_info); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpStr_);
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
pr($httpResponse ); die;
```

Response Code:

> 2017-05-05T22:05:24.585-07:00Failure159af6737a82e32250686520003PLATFORMApplicationErrorApplicationAuthentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.

Comment: Who is "we" in the "how we can integrate..."? Like, you and me, we? I wasn't aware I had a weekend job...I think **you** should make an attempt and post that attempt. I would start with the PayPal documentation.

Comment: Definitelly: you do, we wait.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you're using sandbox environment to test Adaptive Chained Payment. If so kindly use the sandbox account credentials, APP-ID as APP-80W284485P519543T and end point as  $API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";

For Live you need to request for APP ID and set the endpoint to live. Use live account credentials.

For PHP code Click [here](https://github.com/braintreedev/paypal-adaptive-payments-wrapper-php/blob/203cad865f06abd9d772603cbea729bf1cbc9072/adaptive-payments.php)

Comment: public function call($options = [], $method) {
    $this->prepare($options);
    return $this->_curl($this->api_url($method), $options, $this->headers($this->config));
  }
Hello Sir, I go to your suggest link and found this method so please tell me the call() function parameter(($options = [], $method) value in detail with an example.

Comment: Method is what method you need to cal, just specify that method.

Comment: you did not understand my question  once again i want to say that "in call() function here two parameters passed first is $options as an array format and second is method as string type value. so now please tell me you that $options and $methods value with example. means in options array what i need to pass the index or there values."